# Trackball controls doesn't work in new build of three.js

Tags: three.js, trackball

I'm trying to make a simulation consisting of many lines. Up until now I had Three.js v45 and Trackball Controls and it worked fine.

I then tried to implement my lines in a buffer geometry (as in this example: http://fzwoch.project-sheol.org/three.js/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html)

but for that I needed to update to the newer Three.js build. And Trackball Controls doesn't work anymore! Am I missing something? How can I get both to work?

Thank you,
Kasia

Answer (score 7):

First have you noticed that the controls changed location? Now you have to add in your html file:

```
<script src="three.js/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```

You should also check the migration notes https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration to see if anything else changed for your code from the r45 release to r55 (current).

Comment: Thank you very much! I had downloaded TrackballControls and had it locally, but for some reason it didn't work with the new build... Adding the url does. !! Great, thank you!